# Type of field 'myField' is concrete class 'MyClass'

Tags: java, android, compiler-warnings, android-lint

I am preparing my android application for production so I have enabled most lint warnings. One particular warning is wide spread, but I don't understand it.

Here is the warning:

> Type of field 'loginF' is concrete class 'LoginFragment'

And here is the description:

> Reports any instance fields whose type is declared to be a concrete class, rather than an interface. Such declarations may represent a failure of abstraction, and may make testing more difficult. Declarations whose classes come from system or third-party libraries will not be reported by this inspection.

Any elaboration would be appreciated.
Note: The IDE I am using is 'Android Studio'.

Comment: Can you post the LoginFragment class?

Comment: I think it's suggesting that you should store your variable as an interface type, `Fragment` in this case.  As that'll keep things more abstract and thus easier to mock out for testing/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complaining because you're coupling this class (which contains the `loginF` field) with LoginFragment; if you change LoginFragment, you may have to change this class.

Alternatively, look at the methods you're using on LoginFragment in this class. Do they collectively form some behaviour that you can specify in an interface?

e.g. if the only method you call on `loginF` is `initiateLogin()`, then perhaps you can have:

```
interface Login {
    void initiateLogin();
}

class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements Login {
    @Override
    public void initiateLogin() {
        // do login
    }
}
```

such that instead of declaring `LoginFragment loginF = new LoginFragment();`, you use `Login login = new LoginFragment()`.

Then you can change `LoginFragment` so long as it keeps `initiateLogin()` method, or even swap out `new LoginFragment()` for any other implementation of `Login`, which might be useful for mocking in tests.

A very contrived example. I would suggest using the default lint config, not this super strict one.